# Adaptive Issuance Toggle Vote

Tags: adaptive-issuance

My question is regarding the description of the EMA in [this blog post](https://research-development.nomadic-labs.com/adaptive-issuance.html) from Nomadic Labs. Under "Activation Vote":

> The Voting phase is driven by an Exponential moving average (EMA)
> whose half-life is 2 weeks. That is, it takes two weeks for the EMA to
> raise from 0% to 50% assuming only On votes are cast.

> The target threshold is a supermajority of 80% of On votes over On plus Off votes.

I'm not clear on the relationship between the supper-majority and the EMA. Is a super-majority required to progress the EMA?

Answer (score 0):

The EMA represents an average of the opinion of bakers. It ranges in the 0% - 100% interval (0% means no baker votes `On`, 100% means no baker votes `Off`) and it is updated in each block.

Also in each block, the protocol checks if the value of the EMA is above 80%. If the EMA is above 80%, we say that the super-majority is reached and some things happen (essentially, adaptive issuance is set to activate a few cycles later).

Comment: Do I understand correctly that, given the 2 week half life, activation would require more than 80% of "on"/"off" votes to reach an 80% EMA?

Comment: Activation requires 80% of "on"/("on" + "off").